# Azure Chatbot with IE11

Tags: azure

I know I need to use the webchat-es5.js but I get an Error while implementing "styleOptions".

```
const styleOptions = {
    XXXXXX
};


window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
        secret: XXXX
    }),
    styleOptions
},
document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

Where do I need to put this? It is no async function, I know async functions aren't working in IE11.

This is from a sample, I am new to bots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put the whole "styleOptions into "renderWebChat":

```
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
        secret: XXXX
    }),
    styleOptions: {
        XXXXXX
    }
},
document.getElementById('webchat'));
```